# Phing - Installing and using with MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, phing

I have successfully installed Phing but have a few questions.  Right now, in order to use it I have to open up the Terminal and change directory to my **/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.7/bin**  and then have to do:

```
./phing -f /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Build-System/build/build.xml
```

I have a feeling I am doing something wrong cause that's pretty long and all tutorials I read just do Phing -f build.xml and all of these short commands.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?  Not sure if you need more information but I installed it using [this](http://www.torkiljohnsen.com/2009/04/06/installing-phing-on-mamp-mac-osx/) tutorial.  Do I have to change directories every time to my MAMP php bin and then use a full path to the build.xml file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually run the command just by using `phing` from the directory where you have your `build.xml` located. That requires you to have the phing executable in your system path. I haven't tried this in MAMP but if you know how to set your system PATH then this should be quite easy to fix.